# Is this function convex or concave

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Consider the following function:

$$f:(0, \infty)^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}: (\phi,\psi) \rightarrow \frac{\phi}{\psi}$$

Is this function convex or concave? (Or neither?)

I tried by calculating the Hessian matrix:
$$H_f (\phi,\psi) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & - \frac{1}{\psi^2} \\
- \frac{1}{\psi^2} & \frac{2\phi}{\psi^3} & \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
but I could not determine whether it was positve or negativ definite. Any ideas?

Comment: What conditions do you have on $\phi$ and $\psi$?

Comment: If you fix $\phi$, you have a strictly $_____$ section of $f$, so that rules out one thing.

Comment: And by the way, computing the Hesse matrix should not be messy in this case.

Comment: You are right, calculating the matrix itself is not that hard, but I failed to determine whether it is definite. Sorry for being inprecise.

Comment: Okay, the Hesse matrix is correct. What is its determinant?

Comment: I am not that skilled in linear algebra but don't I have to find the eigevalues? The determinant is $\frac{-1}{\psi^4}$.

Comment: You used to call it $\psi$ rather than $y$ before, but that's a small glitch. The important thing is that you can read off the sign of the determinant, it's negative. Then you should know [Sylvester's criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion).

Answer (score 0):

So, you're using the fact that a $C^2$ function

$$f \; \text{is convex} \; \iff \; f'' \; \text{is positive semidefinite}$$

and you can use the fact that a *symmetric* matrix $A$ is

$$\text{ positive semi-definite} \; \iff \text{All principal minors}\; \Delta_k \geq 0$$

You can also see that the *principal minors* of your Hessain are $0, \dfrac{2\phi}{\psi^3}, -\dfrac{1}{\psi^4}$ which guarantees $f$ is *not* convex.